# Selenium program not running without static wait

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenide, selenium-java

There was another StackOverFlow question for which I had to write a program. My program was not working at all. The program is working fine when we debug it. It's failing at other times.

I assumed that it could be due to sync issues. So, changed all my known ExpectedConditions inbuilt methods as well as my own methods but none worked. Once I add a Thread.Sleep() for 1 sec, it worked.

Why is that sleep - `customWait(1)` required here? Can't we write this program without sleep?

```
public class Eljur {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static final Duration TIMEOUT_DURATION = Duration.ofSeconds(30);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://eljur.ru/login");
        customWait(1);
        findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form-select-button__placeholder")).click();
        findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-input__input")).sendKeys("Y");
        findElements(By.cssSelector("div.form-select-option")).get(0).click();
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void customWait(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000L);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static WebElement findElement(By by) {
            return waitFor(elementToBeClickable(by));
    }

    public static List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
            return waitFor(numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(by,0));
    }

    public static<T> T waitFor(Function<WebDriver,T> function) {
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT_DURATION)
                    .until(function);
    }
}
```

Selenide implementation also poses the same problem. Not working without the static wait.

```
open("https://eljur.ru/login");
Thread.sleep(1000);
$("div.form-select-button__placeholder").shouldBe(enabled).shouldBe(visible).shouldBe(interactable).click();
$("input.form-input__input").sendKeys("Y");
$$("div.form-select-option").get(0).click();
Selenide.closeWebDriver();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed that the app you are mentioning here needs to wait for its ssr tasks to finish which can be spotted from a small ssr attribute on one elemnt you can wait on it. The fixed code here as below.

````
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan;

public class Main {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static final Duration TIMEOUT_DURATION = Duration.ofSeconds(30);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://eljur.ru/login");
        waitFor((iDriver -> findElement(By.cssSelector("astro-island")).getAttribute("ssr")==null));
        findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form-select-button__placeholder")).click();
        findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-input__input")).sendKeys("Y");
        findElements(By.cssSelector("div.form-select-option")).get(0).click();
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void customWait(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000L);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static WebElement findElement(By by) {
        return waitFor(elementToBeClickable(by));
    }

    public static List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
        return waitFor(numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(by, 0));
    }

    public static <T> T waitFor(Function<WebDriver, T> function) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT_DURATION)
                .until(function);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have to just find the parent element for the `div.form-select-button__placeholder`

Below is the selenide code that worked!

```java
@Test
void demoTest() {
  Selenide.open("https://eljur.ru/login");
  $("div.form-select-button__placeholder")
      .parent()
      .shouldBe(Condition.visible)
      .click();
  $("input.form-input__input").shouldBe(Condition.visible)
      .sendKeys("Y");
  $$("div.form-select-option")
      .shouldHave(CollectionCondition.sizeGreaterThan(0))
      .get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amuthan. I tried in 2 different machines Mac M1, Mac Intel i7. Facing issues on both. So, am not making it as accepted for now.